# .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() function broken?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm using this very basic fading slide show of Chris Coyier's: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-auto-playing-slideshow/

Everything works fine, except I want multiple slideshows, each being a thumbnail. So when I added multiple of the same thing, it broke. I noticed that it uses `id` of `slideshow`, and `id`s have to be unique, so I changed it to a `class`. Everything now works, but it seems to have broken the `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` functions? Or at least, that's what it appears to have done. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QRZKE/

**HTML**:

```
<div class="thumb" id="first">
    <span><img src="http://thebarking.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/biscuit.jpg"></span>
    <div><img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m33f16g9Li1r21nejo1_400.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://www.creameryschoolofmusic.com/template/upload_images/Guitar-guitar-10566054-1920-1200.jpg"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="thumb" id="second">
    <span><img src="http://thebarking.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/biscuit.jpg"></span>
    <div><img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m33f16g9Li1r21nejo1_400.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://www.creameryschoolofmusic.com/template/upload_images/Guitar-guitar-10566054-1920-1200.jpg"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="thumb" id="third">
    <span><img src="http://thebarking.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/biscuit.jpg"></span>
    <div><img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m33f16g9Li1r21nejo1_400.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://www.creameryschoolofmusic.com/template/upload_images/Guitar-guitar-10566054-1920-1200.jpg"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="thumb" id="fourth">
    <span><img src="http://thebarking.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/biscuit.jpg"></span>
    <div><img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m33f16g9Li1r21nejo1_400.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://www.creameryschoolofmusic.com/template/upload_images/Guitar-guitar-10566054-1920-1200.jpg"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="thumb" id="fifth">
    <span><img src="http://thebarking.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/biscuit.jpg"></span>
    <div><img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m33f16g9Li1r21nejo1_400.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://www.creameryschoolofmusic.com/template/upload_images/Guitar-guitar-10566054-1920-1200.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .thumb {
        position: relative;
        width: 240px;
        height: 240px;
        padding: 10px;
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    }

    .thumb > div {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        bottom: 10px;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .thumb > span {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        bottom: 10px;
        z-index: 3;
        -webkit-transition: all .65s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: all .65s ease-in;
        -ms-transition: all .65s ease-in;
        -o-transition: all .65s ease-in;
        transition: all .65s ease-in;
    }

    .thumb > span:hover {
        opacity: 0;

    }

    .thumb img {
        height: 240px;
        width: 240px;
    }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".thumb > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function() {
    $(".thumb > div:first")
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo(".thumb");
}, 2500);
});
```

*Note:* I added an image inside some `span`s which covers the slide show, and you have to hover over to make it go away (as if to start the slideshow after hovering over it).

Any ideas? Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** I found out that if I remove the other slideshows (having only one), the fade effect works fine. It's only once I add multiple. But classes are allowed to be non-unique, right? So why is the script breaking? (And it's not like the actual script is breaking, it's only the fading effect, otherwise the slider works fine!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the `appendTo('.thumb')` that will append to all your sliders.  And, your span thing makes it repeat the loop between the 2nd and 3rd pictures, never reshowing the 1st.  I'd get rid of the css to fake the slideshow not showing and add the interval on hover.  I'd do it this way (http://jsfiddle.net/QRZKE/18/):

CSS

```
 .thumb {
        position: relative;
        width: 240px;
        height: 240px;
        padding: 10px;
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    }

    .thumb > div {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        bottom: 10px;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .thumb img {
        height: 240px;
        width: 240px;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="thumb" id="first">
    <div><img src="http://thebarking.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/biscuit.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m33f16g9Li1r21nejo1_400.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="http://www.creameryschoolofmusic.com/template/upload_images/Guitar-guitar-10566054-1920-1200.jpg"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="thumb" id="second">
    <div><img src="http://thebarking.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/biscuit.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m33f16g9Li1r21nejo1_400.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://www.creameryschoolofmusic.com/template/upload_images/Guitar-guitar-10566054-1920-1200.jpg"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="thumb" id="third">
    <div><img src="http://thebarking.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/biscuit.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m33f16g9Li1r21nejo1_400.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://www.creameryschoolofmusic.com/template/upload_images/Guitar-guitar-10566054-1920-1200.jpg"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="thumb" id="fourth">
    <div><img src="http://thebarking.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/biscuit.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m33f16g9Li1r21nejo1_400.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="http://www.creameryschoolofmusic.com/template/upload_images/Guitar-guitar-10566054-1920-1200.jpg"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="thumb" id="fifth">
    <div><img src="http://thebarking.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/biscuit.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m33f16g9Li1r21nejo1_400.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://www.creameryschoolofmusic.com/template/upload_images/Guitar-guitar-10566054-1920-1200.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var interval;
    $('.thumb').each( function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#" + id + " > div:gt(0)").hide();
    });

    $('.thumb').hover(function() {
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(id);
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            $("#" + id + " > div:first")
                .fadeOut(1000)
                .next()
                .fadeIn(1000)
                .end()
                .appendTo("#" + id);
        }, 2500);
    }, function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would remove the spans and expand the javascript. For example you could use `mouseenter: function(){ // start interval}` and reset it using `mouseleave: function(){ // reset interval }`.

Although this might not solve your problem, you got less code to worry about:)